# How to configure python with --enable-shared on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python-3.x, heroku, flask, mod-wsgi, ubuntu-18.04

I have a flask application which I'm trying to deploy to heroku. I'm trying to do this through my virtual box where I'm running ubuntu 18.04 .

Up on command : git push heroku master

I see a warning :

```
WARNING: The Python installation you are using does not appear to have  
  been installed with a shared library, or in the case of MacOS X, as a
  framework. Where these are not present, the compilation of mod_wsgi may
  fail, or if it does succeed, will result in extra memory being used by all 
  processes at run time as a result of the static library needing to
   be loaded in its entirety to every process. It is highly recommended
   that you reinstall the Python installation being used from source code,
   supplying the '--enable-shared' option to the 'configure' script when
    configuring the source code prior to building and installing it.
```

and it fails with an error message:

```
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
remote:            collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
remote:            error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I understand that I need to install python with --enable-shared flag in the "configure" script. but I don't seem to find the configure script at all in my python installation under bin or python folder. This is where I'm stuck since 3 days and its frustrating; I don't really have an idea of how to re-install python with such a flag .. After going through many posts I tried the following steps:

1) Downloaded python from the url: https://www.python.org/downloads/source/

2) Ran the command: ./configure --prefix=/opt/python --enable-shared

followed by make

and make install

3) Copied the shared object files to my original python directory

The output to the command: ldd  ** path **/anaconda3/bin/python gives me:

```
libpython3.6m.so.1.0 => /usr/anaconda3/bin/../lib/libpython3.6m.so.1.0 
(0x00007f902dd2e000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 
(0x00007f902db0e000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f902d906000)
libutil.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libutil.so.1 (0x00007f902d6fe000)
 librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f902d4f6000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f902d156000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f902cd5e000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f902e26e000)
```

Yet, when I tried to deploy the app, I see the same warning of --enable-shared and the same error message of gcc. I can't seem to figure out how to properly enable my python installation to have shared object. Please note that I'm a total newbie to ubuntu, I really appreciate any leads into solving this issue.

P.S: My mod_wsgi installation was successful and I was able to run the app locally through mod_wsgi.

Comment: Guys, I've been working on this since over a week, I'm totally not able to figure this out on my own ..... I would really appreciate if anyone could give any leads. I'm really counting on experts' advise to resolve this...

Comment: Can anyone please look into this ??

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to use custom build of python3, you can try to install `python3.6-dev` package through apt, it added shared libs for me.